# How to use e.preventDefault properly here?

Tags: javascript, dom

I might be overlooking something silly but can someone tell me as to why my .preventDefault() is not working and its reloading the page every time i submit

```
const text = document.querySelector('#text');
const amount = document.querySelector('#amount');
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const balance = document.querySelector('#balance');
const moneyPlus = document.querySelector('#money-plus');
const moneyminus = document.querySelector('#money-minus');

const list = document.querySelector('.list');

const textval = text.value;
const amountval = amount.value;

btn.addEventListener('submit', (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(text.value);
    const item = document.createElement('li');
    item.classList.add('plus');
    item.innerHTML = `
        ${textval} ${amountval}
    `
    list.appendChild(item);
    console.log(list);
});
console.log(textval);
```

Comment: Do you first load HTML or JS? Is `btn` correct element? Is `btn` added dynamically? Is this event actually gets called?

Comment: The `submit` event is fired from the `<form>` element, not the button.

Comment: i loaded html 1st but ok ill try the form thing